# How do get Ubuntu to stop modifying /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dhcp

I want to manually set my `resolv.conf` and have Ubuntu not automatically change it later.

**How do I get Ubuntu to stop modifying `resolv.conf`?**

I have already set "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only" in the network settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question & answer set:

[resolv.conf not working properly with Ethernet in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/120173/resolv-conf-not-working-properly-with-ethernet-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a recent version of Ubuntu (I run 12.04 at this time), you will notice that /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink. To stop automatic updates to the file, remove the symlink and replace it with a file with the desired static contents.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get remove resolvconf`?

Comment: My question could have been phrased better. I needed to set the priority of DNS servers, so editing dhclient's config file was better.

Comment: Removing resolvconf forces removal of ubuntu-minimal, which provides a lot of other barebones utilities, which are recommended to not be removed.